# Force re-render / refresh table

Tags: angular, typescript

After I choose `select` option to make API call for new datasource - my table renders appears before fetching data and he is empty. And if I choose another `select` option it shows me previous data for previous option

Tried to put triggers, awaits, promises

```
ngOnInit() {
    getAllRoutes();
    this.currentRouteControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(takeUntil(this._unsubscribe))
      .subscribe((val: Route) => {
         this.commonCatalogueService.getRouteScheduleByRouteId(val.id)
            .subscribe((data:any) => this.dataSource = data)});
    }
```

I expect to render table ONLY after I fetched data.
UPD: Select list items will be fetched in ngOnInit and then added to array. This array will be added to select option via ngFor

```
<select class="m-r-20" [formControl]="currentRouteControl">
          <option *ngFor="let route of (routes$ | async)" [ngValue]="route.route">{{
            route.route.number
            }}</option>
        </select>

private routesSubject: BehaviorSubject<RouteWrapper[]> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
routes$ = this.routesSubject.asObservable();

getAllRoutes() {
    this.isLoadingResults = true;
    this.commonCatalogueService
      .getRouteWrappers()
      .pipe(takeUntil(this._unsubscribe))
      .subscribe(val => {
        this.routesSubject.next(val);
        this.isLoadingResults = false;
      });
  }
```

Comment: the problem might be with `select` control. check if `val.id` is in sync with the selection

Comment: Can you give some detail's about how you're changing the select option and how this new component listens to that change?

Comment: when you change the select first time, verify whether the network request are sent or not?

Comment: @Ethernetz Added more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imported `ChangeDetectorRef` to update displayed info as soon as data fetched and added it after assigning subscription data.

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
constructor( private cd: ChangeDetectorRef ){}

this.commonCatalogueService.getRouteScheduleByRouteId(id)
            .subscribe((data:any) => {
                                      this.dataSource = data;
                                      this.cd.detectChanges();
                                      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can control when a template is rendered using Angular's `NgIf`, which only includes a template when its expression evaluates to true.

```
<table *ngIf="dataSource"></table>
```

Now, the table above will only be rendered when `dataSource` is defined/has a value, as `undefined` is a falsy value in Javascript.

Comment: OP is facing an issue where the datasource is populated with the previous `select` control selection. your answer would not solve the problem

Comment: Well it will be showing me previous data source for previous select option, not selected one